# python equivalent to cmd's "for %%a in (%*) do"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a python beginner and would like to be able to drop a video file on a python script and run multiple FFMPEG commands on it, passing the file name as a variable for the output file name.
I got bits and pieces of commands. I would appreciate a basic functioning script that I could edit myself.
I currently use a windows batch that reads:

```
FOR %%a IN (%*) do (
c:\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~a" "do some stuff" "D:\%%~na\%%~na_360.mp4"
c:\ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~a" "do some stuff" "D:\%%~na\%%~na_480.mp4"
)
```

I'm thinking Python as this should run multi platform (Win, Mac, Linux) and python has FFMPEG pipes which makes it fast.

Answer (score 2):

`%*` iterates over arguments given to the program. In python, these are available in `sys.argv`, but the first argument `argv[0]` is the name of the program itself; thus for the other arguments we use `sys.argv[1:]`. The `~n` stands for the file name, which in Python can be achieved with the help of `os.path.basename`; also we use `subprocess.call` to execute programs as it is safer than `os.system`; `r''` raw strings are needed because `\` is used for escaping in normal Python strings; though a raw string does not work for a string ending in `\\` -  we need `'D:\\'`.

Thus we'd get:

```
import sys
from subprocess import call
from os.path import basename, join, splitext

for a in sys.argv[1:]:
    base, _ = splitext(basename(a))

    # target_prefix is D:\%%~na\%%~na
    target_prefix = join('d:\\', base, base)
    args = [r'c:\ffmpeg.exe', '-i', a, 'do', 'some', 'stuff']

    call(args + [target_prefix + '_360.mp4'])
    call(args + [target_prefix + '_480.mp4'])
```

Comment: Your answer has taught me a lot. Though the script opens with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on the closing bracket of "for a in sys.argv[1:]" and closes right away.

Comment: @o_ren I do not have windows so I didn't bother testing :D fixed

Comment: This is starting to look good. FFMPEG starts to encode but it seems it doesn't get the output file and/or path parameters. In the code above, a file named somefile.avi should end up at d:\somefile_360.mp4. Right?

Comment: ah, it would go to d:\\somefile.avi\\somefile.avi_360.mp4 ;) does ~n split the extension too?

Comment: @o_ren using splitext to remove the `.avi`; `splitext` returns a tuple of `filename`, `.ext`, so we drop the other in the dummy `_` variable.

Comment: splitext is working perfect but FFMPEG is still complaining about the output filename.
when I do -  print (args + [target_prefix + '_480.mp4']) I get:
['c:\\ffmpeg.exe', '-i', 'd:\\somefile.avi, '-c:v copy', 'd:\\somefile\\somefile\\somefile_360.mp4']
Is this valid? because it's not working :(